# Query to select last order (entry) of every product belonging to user that's not returned

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am stuck with rather confusing query.

Assume I have a ProductLending table that tracks what product each user has borrowed, when it was renewed, was it returned or not etc.. Given a user, I want to be able to select, all unique products that are still with the user.

table example:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````
userid    DateRenewed    ProductId    isReturned
````````````````````````````````````````````````
1        2011-07-21      15           0
1        2011-08-20      16           0
1        2011-09-21      15           1
2        2011-09-21      17           0
1        2011-09-21      15           0
`````````````````````````````````````````````````

This is a mock up so sorry if it's not accurate.

Now, given userId = 1, I want to select just unique productId that are NOT returned, but are with the user. So this should give me **15, 16** as result, as even though 15 was returned, it was re-borrowed. If we delete the last row, then the result would just be 16, since user has only 16 with him.

I tried ordering by dateRenewed and selecting top 1 but it did totally something else.. how do I construct a query for this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If product is not returned by user, then the sum of bought products must be larger than sum of returned products

```
SELECT userid,ProductId FROM <table>
GROUP BY userid,ProductId HAVING SUM(CASE CAST(isReturned AS INT) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CAST(isReturned AS INT))>0
```

Comment: I like this, the only issue is going to be if IsReturned is a bit column (which I would expect it to be). If your column is bit, you'll have to change your query to ...-SUM(CAST(isReturned AS INT))>0

Comment: Sure. Don't know the specs of MSSQL2008 exactly, but SQL2005 doesn't support real bit columns, afaik

Comment: Hi, this seems odd, do you mean to say, "sum of bought product must be laster than sum of returned product - **FOR EACH PRODUCT**" ? because, a user could borrow 5 products and then return all 5, so now, above assumption is false and it would return zero rows (which is what I want) - do I understand this correctly? sorry, but this is confusing!

Comment: @Mike yes, I have had to convert isReturned to int to get this to work

Comment: @LocustHorde my statement counts for every(!) user and product how much items are sold and how much are returned. if sum of sold items is larger than sum of returned products then the combination of user/product is returned

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;WITH qry AS
(
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userID, ProductID ORDER BY DateRenewed DESC) rn
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT * 
  FROM qry
WHERE rn = 1 AND isReturned = 0;
```

Comment: Hi, I am actually going to have to convert this into Criterion api (nhibernate) - just wondering if this is possible at all!

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct ProductId
from TABLE_NAME t1
where UserId= @UserId 
and IsReturned = 0
and not exists
(
   select *
   from TABLE_NAME t2
   where t2.UserId =  t1.UserId
   and  t2.ProductId = t1.ProductId
   and t2.IsReturned = 1 
   and t2.DateRenewed > t1.DateRenewed
)
```